# Trying to hide a view but I need help in trying to move the code to the asset library and only have a reference on the "page"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to customize the page for a view to not display a specific view (aka I would like to hide another view from a specific view's page).  Ideally based on group membership.  The eventual goal is to have all my code in my site assets to allow for re-use on other pages/views.

I have the code that will remove the view and if I place it in the Script Editor, it works.  Since I am trying to put all my code in my site assets, once I move it to the sites assets library and then I add my reference, the code no longer runs.

My code in the Site Assets is the following: (this same code surrounded by  tags functions when on the page and in a script editor.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {
  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {
        Header: function (ctx, columns) {
          var views = JSON.parse(ctx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
          //display all View options except 'Create View' & 'Modify View'
          ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = views.length; 
     views = views.filter(function (view) {
        console.log(view.DisplayText, view);
        var isMenu=view.MenuOptionType===2;
        return isMenu || view.DisplayText.indexOf('Owner') <0; // false will not be returned
      });

      ctx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions = JSON.stringify(views);//create string defintion again
      return RenderHeaderTemplate(ctx, columns); //render default Header template
    }
  }
    });
  }
RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/hideview.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

My reference that I now add in my script editor to reference the above code from the site Assets library is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/js-test/HideOwnerViews.js"></script>
```

I would like the functionality of hiding the view with the code in the site assets library and not directly embedded in the page.

Comment: I get that this will work using a CEWP, but why not the Script Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your js library host in root web, reference the library as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/js-test/HideOwnerViews.js"></script>
```

If your js library host in child web, reference the library as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/child/SiteAssets/js-test/HideOwnerViews.js"></script>
```

Comment: All my other references I am using the ../SiteAssets ... and it works.  My thoughts that it matters how and when it is called.  I'm not very fluent on the different ways SharePoint needs to be firing off it's scripting language.  Some of it is as the document is ready, some after all the scripts are loaded, ...  I don't have a good reference or an understanding of the options here and more specifically how to implement which options when.

Comment: Use developer tool to check your js library loaded correctly, while this related to library reference(.net relative path) according to my experience.